# How to get the full url of the current api NOT of the original requestor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, httprequest

**Background**

I have a local backend API at this address:

http://localhost:54641/orders

And a clientside UI at:

http://localhost:3000/

**What I need**

The UI does a call to the backend, to list all available orders. This includes information on an attachment for each order. It may or not be there. If there is an attachment, you *should* get this response from the API, for each order:

```
{
  "orderReference": "123456",
  "actions": { "download": "http://localhost:54641/orders/123456/download" }
}
```

Actions will be `{}` if there's no attachment available.

**However**

What I *do* get, is this:

```
{
  "orderReference": "123456",
  "actions": { "download": "http://localhost:3000/orders/123456/download" }
}
```

Which doesn't exist, ofcourse.

**What I have right now**

Is this code to build the full url, which is going wrong:

```
var baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
var uri = Url.Route("DownloadLabel", new {orderReference });
var fullUrl = $"{baseUrl}{uri}";
```

As in, it returns the requestor's full url path, not that of the current API.

**Question**

> What can I do to get the API url in the response?

So, it should return like this:

http://localhost:54641/orders/123456/download

Comment: @mjwills: It is `http://localhost:3000`, it should be `http://localhost:54641`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I used httpcontext instead:

```
var baseUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
var uri = Url.Route("DownloadLabel", new {orderReference });
var fullUrl = $"{baseUrl}{uri}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this,

```
string fullUrl=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
var wantedUrl= fullUrl.SubString(0,fullUrl.IndexOf("/orders"))+"/orders/"+orderReference+"/download";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will accept my own answer as the solution, because what you're proposing is more error prone, as you're building the url manually instead of using an official method.